# how to search table where like '%data%' or like '%data%' and deleted = 0?

Tags: php, mysql

i have some struggle to search table.
here the example

```
SELECT * FROM table_tutup_kas 
LEFT JOIN table_formulir_pelita 
  ON table_formulir_pelita.id_formulir=table_tutup_kas.id_formulir  
WHERE nomor_formulir LIKE '%mikha%' or harga_pelita LIKE '%5%' and  deleted=0
```

the result still showing data with status deleted=1.
any other method for fix my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AND` logical operator has a higher precedence than `OR` . Try using parenthesis :

```
SELECT * FROM table_tutup_kas 
LEFT JOIN table_formulir_pelita 
  ON table_formulir_pelita.id_formulir=table_tutup_kas.id_formulir  
WHERE (nomor_formulir LIKE '%mikha%' or harga_pelita LIKE '%5%' ) and  deleted=0 ;
```